# how civicrm class prepared on body tag

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, ui

Does anybody have an idea, how and where we build CiviCRM class on body tag.?
[image]
E.g. 1

- URL:https://domain.com/civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend?reset=1
- Class : html not-front logged-in page-civicrm page-civicrm-admin page-civicrm-admin-setting page-civicrm-admin-setting-updateconfigbackend

E.g. 2

- URL: https://domain.com/civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1
- Class: html not-front logged-in page-civicrm page-civicrm-admin page-civicrm-admin-setting page-civicrm-admin-setting-path

Basically class build using civicrm url

- page-civicrm-admin-setting-updateconfigbackend
- page-civicrm-admin-setting
- page-civicrm-admin
- page-civicrm

Answer (score 1):

Some of it is added via javascript, e.g. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.15.2/js/crm.menubar.js#L104

But as this ticket notes the rest depends a bit on the CMS and the theme and is inconsistent:   https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/300

Answer (score 1):

I was using Drupal 8 adminimal theme and shoreditch civicrm theme. but civicrm tab for contact were not showing correctly as expected. Found issue that civicrm class build using url path were not present.

Following block should be present in hook_preprocess_HOOK, This is total CMS functionality.

File Ref : adminimal_theme/adminimal_theme.theme

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for HTML document templates.
 */
function adminimal_theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Add adminimal class to the body.
  $path_args = explode('/', \Drupal::request()->getPathInfo());
  $path_args = array_filter($path_args);
  if ($suggestions = theme_get_suggestions($path_args, 'page', '-')) {
    foreach ($suggestions as $suggestion) {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $suggestion;
    }
  }
}
```